# nested exception is web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' not supported for bodyType

Tags: spring-webclient

Created a REST Webservice(Service 1) which tries to consume another service(Service 2) which returns Content-Type = "text/html;charset=utf-8"

my WebClient code that consumes another service:

```
ublic <T, N> N invokeService(String endPointUrl, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpHeaders headers, T requestPayload,
            Class<T> requestPlayLoadClass, Class<N> serviceResponseClass) {
    UriSpec<RequestBodySpec> uriSpec = webclient.method(httpMethod);
    RequestBodySpec bodySpec = uriSpec.uri(endPointUrl);
    RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec = buildRequest(headers, requestPayload, requestPlayLoadClass, bodySpec);

    Mono<N> res = headersSpec.retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> handle4xxError(clientResponse))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> handle5xxError(clientResponse))
                .bodyToMono(serviceResponseClass);

    return res.block();

}

private <T> RequestHeadersSpec<?> buildRequest(HttpHeaders headers, T requestPayload, Class<T> requestPlayLoadClass,
            RequestBodySpec bodySpec) {
        RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec = bodySpec.headers(clientHeaders -> clientHeaders.addAll(headers));
        if (requestPayload != null && requestPlayLoadClass != null) {
            headersSpec = bodySpec.body(Mono.just(requestPayload), requestPlayLoadClass);
        }
        return headersSpec;
    }
```

I am getting the below error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' not supported for bodyType
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:212) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:216) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
```

Response Pojo class:

```
@Data
public class ServiceResponse{

    private String name;
    private String systemDevice;
    private String key;
}
```

the response which I am receiving:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Connect Servlet Version 6</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H3>Message Response from Connect Servlet for Version 6</H3>
    <BR>Connect Server running servlet <BR>
    <HR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;interface:
    IManagement<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;method: deliverevent<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;contactevent: PauseRecord<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;agent.agent: test<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;agent.systemdevice: Screen Data Source<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;device.systemdevice: test_lab<br>ContactEvent: DEVICE_NOT_IN_CALL
    <HR>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Can anyone please suggest me?

Comment: Well, how do you intend to parse HTML as a pojo? Can you post an example response? Is there even any specific reason why you have that content type?

Comment: thank you for the response. I have added a response to my question. there is not any specific reason but this is a third party service and not able to change anything at this moment.

Answer (score 5):

Since your response is HTML, there is no built in way of converting it directly to a POJO, so you will have to consume the response raw, e.g. as string or byte buffer.

Specify the response class in `bodyToMono` as `String.class`, and then parse the HTML manually using a library of choice. The HTML you posted looks XML conform (i.e. XHTML), so that might make things drastically easier, but only up to the part where you actually extract the string that you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I will try that.